# Template code shows no results

Tags: python, django, templates, django-queryset

I want to show the values of my database in my detail template. Because of my model:

```
class RiskFactor(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    examination = models.CharField(max_length=100, 
                                   choices=Examination_Choice,
                                   default='notchosenyet')
    hypertension = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    diabetes = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to filter the values of the first examination and so I've design my template like this:

```
<ul>
{% for rfac in patient.riskfactor_set.all %}
  {% if rfac.examination == 'FIRST' %}
   <li>Hypertension: {{ rfac.hypertension }}<br/>
      Diabetes: {{ rfac.diabetes }}<br/>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But I got no values shown in my detail page. Any ideas?

Update: Just a dump fault of mine. Had to write 'first' instead of 'FIRST' because of my defined choices..

Comment: can you show the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following to make sure of the case of `FIRST` is correct in the database.  In the view, add the following to your context dictionary:

```
context['factors'] = patient.riskfactor_set.filter(examination__iexact='first')
```

And in your template:

```
<ul>
{% for rfac in factors %}
   <li>Hypertension: {{ rfac.hypertension }}<br/>
      Diabetes: {{ rfac.diabetes }}<br/>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```